# Comprimir archivos y carpetas de diferentes ubicaciones en un único .ZIP o .RAR

Tags: c#, zip, rutas

Es posible comprimir archivos y/o directorios de diferentes ubicaciones en un único archivo `.ZIP` o `.RAR`, es decir, sin tener que pasar por la instancia previa de copiar todo a un directorio temporal y allí comprimir todo.

Por ejemplo, tengo las carpetas `C:\Carpeta1` y `C:\Carpeta2` y los archivos `C:\Carpeta3\Archivo1.arc` y `D:\Carpeta4\Archivo2.arc` y quiero armar un único archivo `.ZIP` o `.RAR` que contenga estos 4 elementos.

Comment: Si, suena posible lo que pides... pero has de mostrar lo que has intentado junto a por qué no te funciona: errores, problemas, resultado no esperado? Para más informacion mira  [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Con que lenguaje? Si es desde el SO mira la documentacion oficial de WinRaR -> https://www.winrar.es/soporte/manual/HELPCommandLineSyntax

Comment: @Lithorell el lenguaje que utilizo es C#. El compañero lois6b editó mi pregunta y eliminó esa etiqueta.

Comment: Borro mi respuesta de la librería zip4j en java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una librería bastante sencilla de utilizar es [`Ionic.Zip`](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) donde simplemente debes poner el siguiente código para que comprima las carpetas que necesites:

```
using Ionic.Zip;
...


using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddDirectory(@"C:\Carpeta1", "Carpeta1");
    zip.AddDirectory(@"C:\Carpeta2", "Carpeta2");
    zip.Comment = "Archivo comprimido el " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G") ; 
    zip.Save("ArchivoCreado.zip");
}
```

También puedes hacerlo por `ASP.net` con el siguiente código:

```
public async Task downloadFolder(string folder)
{
    string[] folderContents = folder.Split('/');
    string fileName = folderContents[folderContents.Length - 2];
    Response.Clear();
    try
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Ruta" + folder), fileName);
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".zip");
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";
        Response.Write("El directorio está vacío.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Ejemplos como estos y más (contraseñas, archivos específicos, extracción de archivos) los puedes encontrar en su [página de ejemplos](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples).

Comment: Espectacular! Muchas gracias!